# cross compile libxml2 for android has build errors

Tags: android-ndk, libxml2, icu

I am trying to cross compile libxml2 for android , since libxml need icu4c headers , Downloaded from the link https://github.com/android/platform_external_icu4c  and  included the unicode headers and  tried to compiled using ndk-build,,.
 But got the below errors .

```
      obj/local/armeabi/objs/xsml2/encoding.o: In function `xmlUconvWrapper':
      jni/encoding.c:1870: undefined reference to `ucnv_convertEx'
      jni/encoding.c:1865: undefined reference to `ucnv_convertEx'
      obj/local/armeabi/objs/xsml2/encoding.o: In function `closeIcuConverter':
      jni/encoding.c:141: undefined reference to `ucnv_close'
      jni/encoding.c:142: undefined reference to `ucnv_close'
      obj/local/armeabi/objs/xsml2/encoding.o: In function `openIcuConverter':
      jni/encoding.c:109: undefined reference to `ucnv_open'
      jni/encoding.c:119: undefined reference to `ucnv_setFromUCallBack'
      jni/encoding.c:126: undefined reference to `ucnv_open'
      jni/encoding.c:132: undefined reference to `ucnv_close'
      jni/encoding.c:115: undefined reference to `ucnv_setToUCallBack'
      jni/encoding.c:115: undefined reference to `UCNV_FROM_U_CALLBACK_STOP'
      jni/encoding.c:115: undefined reference to `UCNV_TO_U_CALLBACK_STOP'
```

For this errors I included the -L/Android/android-ndk-r8/external/libs  -licui18n -licuuc in Android make file but I get the above errors .
Can some body suggests which  version of icu4c libs has all these functions .

My final goal is to compile libxml2 for android .

Pls somebody through some light to proceed further .

Comment: Are you building ICU yourself? You're compiling against ICU but the NDK does not provide libraries for such (you need to build & link against them on your own)